# Switch the "environment" on Debian linux after the installation?

Tags: linux, installation, debian

When you install Debian linux, there's a dialog in the graphical install system which asks after several steps in which environment you want to stay. There are options between "File environment", "Web environment", "Graphical environment" and some others.

Unluckily, I've also marked the "Graphical environment" on my newly set-up server and want to remove this option. Is there a way to do it? Every time I update my system, packages like Iceweasel, X and other gui related software gets updated too...

And, how is this called? If I search for "environment debian linux" I can't find any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "software selection" screen of the Debian installation -- which lists different desktop environments, "web server", "print server", etc. -- is `tasksel`. You can run it manually to add or remove software sets after the installation:

```
$ sudo tasksel
```

or as `root`:

```
# tasksel
```

Use the arrow keys to move the highlight to the item you want to change, spacebar to toggle it, and then press Tab to move the cursor to the Ok 'button' and press Enter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're referring to but it is most likely a [meta package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages). If you uninstall the programs you want to remove, that should stop them from being updated and it should also remove the meta package.

You can check which metapackages you have installed like this:

```
apt-cache show $(dpkg-query -Wf '${Package}\n') | 
  awk '$1 == "Package:" { pkg = $2 }; 
      $1 == "Section:" && $2 ~ /metapackage/ { print pkg }'
```

In any case, the easiest thing to do would be to remove the packages you don't want. Something like:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome*  xorg* iceweasel
```